# Find marginal distribution of X (Bayesian setting)

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

$X|\theta$ follows $N(\theta,w)$ and
$\theta$ follows $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Both follow a normal distribution but with different mean and variance. I assume it is a Bayesian setting.

How to find the marginal distribution of X? Would mgf be a good way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $Z = X - \theta$.
Then $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0, w)$ and is independent of $\theta$.

As $X = Z + \theta$, it is the sum of two independent normal random variables. Hence $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0 + \mu$ and variance $w^2 + \sigma^2$.